# Where can I view a large iOS codebase to see how it was organized?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mvvm, refactoring

For a new developer building an app, are there projects/repositories I can pull into Xcode to study and see how code, files, folders, MVVM patterns are implemented in a BIG project??

It would be great to analyze and refer to a large code-base that has implemented best coding practices for the problem it solves.

This way I (as a new developer) can be aware of how to organize & refactor my code for a maintainable app.

Thank you!

Comment: Chris, my recommendation is you take a look at how Apple organized their [SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/). Using a layout similar will meet the needs of a nascent project and as your app grows, you can worry more about structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my two cents: don't try to find a large ios code base to study. take a look at smaller, easier-to-consume open source projects and get a feel for what you like / don't like, comparing them against each other. you will find that there is not one set way of doings; if there was, we'd all be doing it! what's important is figuring out what tools / patterns / practices etc. help *you* build the best app that you can (hint: an app that's built is better than one that's not), and you'll only find that out by doing some building yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source projects.

First one that comes to mind is Signal.
https://github.com/signalapp

Here are many projects listed by categories:
https://github.com/dkhamsing/open-source-ios-apps

First one that sprung out was Firefox:
https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios

Google should help you find more, just check out your favorite apps and see if they are open source.

Try to find different kinds of projects, with huge storyboards, with many libraries in the Podfile, ...